# What is the probability of the piñata breaking?

Tags: probability

A pinata breaks if it receives a strong hit or two medium hits. The probability of receiving a strong blow is 1/4, a medium blow 1/4 and the chance of a missed hit is 1/2. Four children are about to hit the pinata. What is the probability of it breaking?

Let P(S) be the probability of it breaking.Let P(D) be the possibility of a strong blow ,P(M) of a medium one and P(A) of missing.

I know I need to take into consideration the fact that I hit it twice, but my math seems to be failing me.

Edit: So, I thought that the possibility of missing four times is (1/4)^4 and the possibility of hitting it with medium power only once is 1/2^5.

Then, (1/2^4)+(1/2^5)=2/2^5.  Now, P =1 - 2/2^5 = 15/16 =0.9375.

Second edit: If the chance of hitting with medium power is four times higher then it is 1/2^3. Which changes the result to 0.8125.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  it will break unless it receive four misses or one medium hit.  Compute the chance of each of these and subtract from $1$.

The Markov chain approach, which would be easier in some other problems, is to consider three states:  original ($O$), damaged ($D$), broken ($B$).  You have transition probabilities from each state to each other, which you can put in a matrix.  The stating state is $\begin {pmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end {pmatrix}$.  Four multiplies by the matrix gets you the probability distribution after the four children.

Comment: Is the answer 0.61538462?

Comment: @MariosAth:  I get a different value.  You should edit your calculation into the question so I/we can comment.  As all the denominators are small powers of $2$, the answer should be a binary fraction.

Comment: I found my mistake. I edited my answer. Is it correct now?

Comment: You are close.  You have missed the same point as the other answer:  the chance of exactly one medium hit is four times higher because any one of the children could be the one to get the hit.

Answer (score 2):

The probability that the pinata doesn't break is $29/32$.
You have to calculate the probability that the pinata break, the probability is $3/32$ be cause the pinata break if the first children missed hit( probability is $1/2$), the second also missed hit(probability is $1/2$) and also the third missed hit( probability is $1/2$) while the last children can missed hit or hit the pinata with a blog hit(probability is $1/2+1/4$); therefore $1- 1/2\cdot 1/2 \cdot1/2\cdot(1/2+1/4)=29/32.$

Comment: This is not correct, as one of the first three could have a medium hit as long as the others miss.

Comment: Yes but only one can hit with a blow hit, therefore it is corre t be cause you can choose one between four children be cause the probability doesn't change

Comment: There are four cases of one medium hit, though.  Any one of the children could have the medium hit.  Letting M be a medium hit and m be a miss, the five cases we need to add are Mmmm, mMmm, mmMm, mmmM, mmmm.  You have only included the last two of these.